# Why does my JMenuBar not activate? (flickers when clicked, but doesn't show up completely)

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent, jmenubar

I am building a `JFrame` that implements a `JMenuBar` across the top. The rest of the frame is a `JComponent`, which contains an animated ball moving around the screen (via a double-buffered raster image). Whenever I click on the menu items, they flicker, but do not fully appear. Is my `JComponent` (which uses `paintComponent()` to draw) covering up my menu for some reason? The whole reason I created a separate `JComponent` was to avoid conflicts between elements. Here is the code for my `JFrame` and `JComponent`.

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creates Game window.
        MyFrame myFrame = new MyFrame();
        DrawingSurface drawingSurface = new DrawingSurface();

        myFrame.add(drawingSurface);
        drawingSurface.setup();

        myFrame.makeMenu();

        drawingSurface.paintGomponent();

    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    /**
     * Default serial version of long defined to suppress serial warning.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyFrame()
    {
        setTitle("Breakout");
        setSize(800,600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Sets location to center of screen (stackoverflow.com)
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void makeMenu()
    {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        // Adds menu "Game" with sub-menu "New", "Pause" and "Exit".
        JMenu game = new JMenu("Game");
        JMenuItem newGame = new JMenuItem("New");
        newGame.setToolTipText("Starts a new game");
        JMenuItem pauseGame = new JMenuItem("Pause");
        pauseGame.setToolTipText("Pauses the game");
        JMenuItem exitGame = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exitGame.setToolTipText("Exits the game");

        // Adds menu "High Score".
        JMenu highScores = new JMenu("High Scores");
        highScores.setToolTipText("Displays high scores");

        // Adds menus to menu bar and sets menu bar to frame.
        game.add(newGame);
        game.add(pauseGame);
        game.add(exitGame);
        menuBar.add(game);
        menuBar.add(highScores);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }
}

class DrawingSurface extends JComponent
{
    private int XResolution = 800;
    private int YResolution = 600;

    private Image raster;
    private Graphics rasterGraphics;


    public void paintGomponent()
    {
        super.paintComponent(rasterGraphics);

        // Player ball used in game.
        Ball ball = new Ball(400, 300, 2.0f, 1.0f);

        while(true)
        {
            // Time for use with sleep, to make game run more smoothly.
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            drawBackground();

            ball.moveBall(ball);
            ball.drawBall(rasterGraphics);

            // Draws buffered raster graphics to frame.
            getGraphics().drawImage(raster, 0, 0, XResolution, YResolution, null);
            long changeInTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            try{Thread.sleep(10-changeInTime);}catch(Exception e){}
        }
    }

    private void drawBackground()
    {
        rasterGraphics.setColor(Color.black);
        rasterGraphics.fillRect(0, 0, XResolution, YResolution);
    }

    public void setup()
    {
        raster = createImage(XResolution, YResolution);
        rasterGraphics = raster.getGraphics();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is my JComponent (which uses paintComponent() to draw) covering up my menu for some reason?

You are not using the paintComponent() method and that is probably the problem. You created you own method with `"G"` instead of a `"C"` and then you are trying to use your Graphics, instead of the Graphics that would normally be passed into the paintComponent() method.

Don't get fancy with your code. Just put the painting code in the paintComponent() method and use its Graphics object.

Don't have a while loop in your painting code and just use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.